# How to restore assigned OnClickListener in OnRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android, return, onclicklistener, onrestoreinstancestate

I currently have some buttons that are assigned an `OnClickListener` based on events. However, when I try to restore everything on a orientation change, the `OnClickListeners` are all reset.

I need a way of putting what `OnClickListener` was assigned to the button into the bundle so I can reassign it in the `OnRestoreInstanceState`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have 50 rep to add a comment.

Any specific reason for needing to save the `OnClickListener` instance as opposed to its variables?

You could make your class implement OnClickListener. That way you'd move any relevant information to your class and easily accessible to your `onSaveInstanceState()` method.

Anyway, if you could provide a code sample of what you're trying to do, it would be very helpful.

Comment: To be honest, the amount of work it would be to change it all. Do you think that is my only option. I'm just doing some research before I commit to changing it all.

Comment: Unless you extend OnClickListener and make it serializable, I don't think there's a way for you to add that to a bundle.
Anyway, by making the class implement it, you could just copy your onClick to the method that will be added to the class, it should be a straightforward change, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory create class that implements View.OnClickListener AND Serializable, initiate it and store reference to it, then on rotation use onSaveInstanceState() to save this to bundle and then in onCreate restore it. But frankly, you should have a really good reason to do that. I can't think of one. That information should be stored in root object that contains listener, you can save its state in that root object and save/restore it normally.